# Sort a Table View by Fivestar Rating Fields

Tags: 7, views, rating

I'm currently using Fivestar-7.x-2.0-alpha2 and Views-7.x-3.7. And running Drupal 7.

I am trying to create a table view that displays the information from fields on a certain node type. In this case, the "Program" node and all of the rating fields (fivestar fields) and two text fields (Discipline and University). You can see what I have currently here.

The problem I am having is I can't seem to get the table to sort properly. I have cleared out the Sort Criteria so there isn't any sorting being applied other than from the table settings (I think?). I went into the table settings for the view and checked off sortable for all of the fields. However, when I try to sort them they either don't change at all (the fivestar and computed fields) or they sort improperly (the University field).

I'm at somewhat of a loss. I've done hours of Googling but I can't seem to come up with any sort of solution. If anyone could offer some advice I would be most appreciative.

I should also note that the "Overall" field is a computed field that averages all of the fivestar fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incredibly late, but I just found the answer to the Fivestar rating issue:

You need to add *"Content: Vote results"* as a View relationship, then sort by *"Vote results: Value"*.

Sorting by "Rating: Average Rating" seems to do nothing, as the queried fields seem to be undefined. This method, however, will work.

Comment: +1 for the late but detailled answer for a question I was about to ask some time soon